# Tiene el formato correcto este view en html?

Tags: html, asp.net, views

Estoy viendo un tutorial de sistema de facturacion en asp mvc pero no se utilizan las mismas propiedades, he tratado de hacerlos funcionar, no tiene error, pero NO muestra el resultado como deberia ser.

```html
@model Harman.Web.ViewModels.OrderView

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "NuevaOrden";
}

<h2>Nueva Orden</h2>

@*<h4>Cliente</h4>*@
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for(model=> model.Cliente.Customerid , "Customerid", class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="Cliente" , class="form-control" />*@
                <select asp-for="Cliente.FullName" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Clientes"></select>
                <span asp-for(model=> model.Cliente.Customerid "",  class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <a asp-action="Agregar Porducto" asp-route-id="" AgregarProducto class="btn btn-primary"></a> 

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saludos. ¿**"[...], pero muestra el resultado como deberia ser.**? Si tu duda es que no se muestra como debe ser te sugiero pongas la imagen de lo esperado y lo obtenido para así entender que pasa y te puedan indicar que revisar.

Comment: Asi luce cuando se ejecuta: https://imgur.com/a/y40CNnC Obviamente no deberia saber ese codigo ahi, tambien deberia mostrar a los clientes que esten registrados pero no lo hace.

Comment: Recien me di cuenta que me falto agregar el "no'' en ''No muestra el resultado como deberia ser'' @RobertoLeOr

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Está en inglés pero ilustra como debe ser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989927/how-to-get-value-from-model-for-html-label

Comment: Trato de implementarlo pero no funciona, el tutorial que veo tiene esos "@html'' pero mi proyecto no los utiliza asi, por lo menos solo los asp-for o select for.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. los `asp-for(model=>...` no le estas colocando el paréntesis de cierre `) `.